# Sphinx Duplicate descriptions with autosummary_imported_members = True

Tags: python-sphinx

In Sphinx-autosummary, I set the autosummary to display methods and classes with `autosummary_imported_members = True`, so I have a clear list of functions and methods. Further, I kept modules in the template as some submodules are imported and have members that I also need documented. However, now, functions and classes are documented twice, as such *and* as modules (`module.submodule.function()` or `module.submodule.file` that contains only the class) in the module documentation.

Is there any way to exclude the "modules" that are already in classes?

It is especially annoying when the `module.submodule.file.class` shouldn't even be accessible as it is not in the `__init__.py` file.

I tried to add custom python functions in the template but it can never find them.

As an example:
My module template is:

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}


.. THIS USES THE MODULE TEMPLATE


.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Module Attributes') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in attributes %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block functions %}
   {% if functions %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Functions') }}

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree:
      :recursive:
   {% for item in functions %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block classes %}
   {% if classes %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Classes') }}

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree:
      :recursive:
   {% for item in classes %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block exceptions %}
   {% if exceptions %}
   .. rubric:: {{ _('Exceptions') }}

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in exceptions %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}





{% block modules %}
{% if modules %}
.. rubric:: Modules

.. autosummary::
   :toctree:
   :recursive:
{% for item in modules %}
   {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If I have a module foo.bar with `__init__.py`:

```
from . import sub
from .tea import tea
from .data_class import DataClass
```

It will show as functions tea, as class DataClass, and as modules `foo.bar.sub`, `foo.bar.tea`, and `foo.bar.data_class`, when I would like it to only show `foo.bar.sub`.